# Agrupar por faixa etária

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Boa noite, tenho que agrupar e contar quantos empregados possuo com sexo e faixa etária. Segue o código html

```
      <div class="card" style="margin-top: 5%;">   
    <div class="card-header text-center">
      Quantificação de Empregados por faixas etárias
    </div>     
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
       <<thead>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Homens</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Mulheres</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>         
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 30%">Maiores de 45 anos</th>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 30%">Entre 18 e 45 anos</th>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 30%">Menores de 18 anos</th>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>                         
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Exemplo, tenho que mostra :

> ```
> Masculino Maiores que 45 anos - 2
> Masculino Entre 18 e 45 anos - 5
> Feminino Maiores que 45 anos - 1
> Feminino Entre 18 e 45 anos - 3
> ```

Segue o código sql estou usando, porém esta dando erro:

```
SELECT *, CASE (funcionario.funcionario_Sexo) 
  WHEN F COUNT(funcionario.funcionario_Sexo) AS sexoF 
  AND 
  CASE (funcionario.funcionario_Sexo) 
  WHEN M COUNT(funcionario.funcionario_Sexo) AS sexoM), 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, `funcionario`.`funcionario_DataNac`, CURDATE()) 
  AS idade_Funcionario 
  FROM `funcionario` WHERE `CodEmpresa` = '30' 
  GROUP BY `funcionario`.`funcionario_Sexo`
```

Achei como fazer, porém esta me retornando a soma igual em todos.

```
SELECT funcionario_DataNac, funcionario_Nome, funcionario_Sexo, 
    COUNT(funcionario_Sexo) AS sexo,

COUNT( CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) > 45 THEN 1 ELSE '' END) AS maiorQue,
COUNT( CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) <= 45 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) >= 18 THEN 1 ELSE '' END) AS entre,
COUNT( CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) < 18 THEN 1 ELSE '' END) AS menosQue

FROM `funcionario`
    WHERE codEmpresa = 30
    GROUP BY funcionario_Sexo
```

[image: Foto dos resultados]

Comment: Qual erro?.....

Comment: Você tem alguma coisa desenvolvida em `PHP` ou a dúvida é somente de `sql`?

Comment: Tenho que gerar o relatório em php via codeigniter, ja tenho a estrutura, porém preciso saber o sql mesmo. ou se possivel até mesmo via o php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro está no uso do [`CASE`](https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/utilizando-select-case-com-mysql); a estrutura deve ser assim:

```
CASE coluna_consultada 
WHEN 'valor_1' THEN 'retorno um'
WHEN 'valor_2' THEN 'retorno dois'
ELSE 'retorno tres' 
END AS valor_adicional`
```

Assim sendo, entendo que seu `case` deveria ser alterado para retornar duas colunas ao invés de como está, exibindo o total de pessoas dos sexos *feminino* e *masculino*:

```
COUNT(CASE (funcionario.funcionario_Sexo) WHEN 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'sexoF',
COUNT(CASE (funcionario.funcionario_Sexo) WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'sexoM'
```

Para a divisão por faixa etária, como serão exibidos os totais por `sexo` em colunas diferentes (`sexoF` e `sexoM`), isso precisará ser levado em conta; assim, serão deverão ser retornadas também colunas diferentes de faixa etária por sexo:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) > 45 AND funcionario_Sexo = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS maiorQueF,
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) > 45 AND funcionario_Sexo = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS maiorQueM,
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) <= 45 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) >= 18 AND funcionario_Sexo = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS entreF,
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) <= 45 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) >= 18 AND funcionario_Sexo = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS entreM,
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) < 18 AND funcionario_Sexo = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS menosQueF,
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) < 18 AND funcionario_Sexo = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS menosQueM,
```

Perceba que alterei a função usada nesse levantamento para `SUM()`, somando *1* (quando a condição for atendida) ou *0* (caso contrário).

Comment: Blz, até ai ok, mas alem disso tenho que mostrar as faixas etárias.

Comment: Na verdade estou testando, vou editar de novo, esta dando erros.

Comment: @JoséLuis alterei a resposta, veja se isso atende.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Deu certinho.

Comment: massa, man.. =]

Answer (score 1):

Outra solução seria trazer os registros agrupados pelo campo SEXO, tipo:

```
select COUNT(*)QTD_SEXO from funcionario

where funcionario_Sexo <> '' // caso o campo aceite vazio

group by funcionario_Sexo 

order by funcionario_Sexo // gera dois registros, sempre o feminino vira primeiro
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer. Obrigado a todos que me deram ajuda. Estarei deixando o código caso alguem precise.

```
SELECT funcionario_DataNac, funcionario_Nome, funcionario_Sexo, 
    COUNT(funcionario_Sexo) AS sexo,

SUM( CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) > 45 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS maiorQue,
SUM( CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) <= 45 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) >= 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS entre,
SUM( CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, funcionario_DataNac, CURDATE()) < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS menosQue

FROM `funcionario`
    WHERE codEmpresa = 30
    GROUP BY funcionario_Sexo
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]